# Excel VBA loop inside loop

Tags: vba, excel, loops

Please help to complete the VBA loop inside loop

```
Sub fill()

Dim FirstDate As Date
Dim LastDate As Date
FirstDate = Range("A1").Value
LastDate = Range("B1").Value

    For i = 0 To LastDate - FirstDate
       For j = 0 To 4
       Cells(4 + i + j, 1) = FirstDate + i
       Cells(4 + j, 2) = j
       Next j
    i = i + j
    Next i

End Sub
```

[Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXeAn.png)

Comment: `I` as an iterator and then `I` as `I=I+j` within the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quick and dirty

```
Sub fill()

    Dim FirstDate As Date, LastDate As Date

    FirstDate = Range("A1").Value
    LastDate = Range("B1").Value
    Dim i As Long, iOffset As Long, j As Long

    For i = 0 To LastDate - FirstDate
        For j = 0 To 3
            Cells(4 + iOffset + j, 1) = FirstDate + i
            Cells(4 + iOffset + j, 2) = j
        Next
        iOffset = iOffset + j
    Next

End Sub
```

alternative code with no loops:

```
Sub fill()

    With Range("A4").Resize(4 * (Range("B1").Value - Range("A1").Value + 1))
        .FormulaR1C1 = "= R1C1+INT(COUNT(R3C:R[-1]C)/4)"
        .Offset(, 1) = Application.Transpose(Split(Left(WorksheetFunction.Rept("0,1,2,3,", .Rows.Count), Len(WorksheetFunction.Rept("0,1,2,3,", .Rows.Count)) - 1), ","))
        .Resize(, 2).Value = .Resize(, 2).Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: if I want another column means for each (0,1,2,3....n) there will be four value "00","15","30","45". [with out loop]